# Mostrar array con guion en lugar de coma

Tags: javascript

Estoy mostrando un array desde javascript usando el siguiente `for`:

```
for (var y = 0; y < arrayHay.length; y++) {
     $(".reporteBody").append('<div class="cajaResult"><h3>Caja #' + arrayHay[y] + "</h3><p>" + arrayMaximo[y] + "</p></div>");
}
```

La cual me la muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo mostrar el mismo array solo que con guion en lugar de la coma?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

**EDITADO**

Estoy tratando con la siguente forma y me sigue dando igual las comas:

```
for (var y = 0; y < arrayHay.length; y++) {
     str = arrayMaximo[y].toString();
     str.replace(",", "-");
     console.log("Cadena nueva:", str);
     $(".reporteBody").append('<div class="cajaResult"><h3>Caja #' + arrayHay[y] + "</h3><p>" + str + "</p></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razones por las que no te funciona y sus soluciones:

1. `replace` cambia la cadena especificada por la nueva cadena... **pero no modifica la cadena original**. Es por ello que no basta con hacer `str.replace(",", "-")` debes asignar el valor de nuevo: `str = str.replace(",", "-")`.
2. Incluso si corriges lo indicado en el paso 1, va a seguir sin funcionar porque tal y como está especificado ese reemplazo, sólo afectará a la primera ocurrencia. Deberías usar expresiones regulares para indicar que quieres que se sustituyan todas las ocurrencias. Eso lo puedes conseguir haciendo `str = str.replace(/,/g, "-")`.

Con esos cambios el código ya funciona:

```js
arrayHay = [1,5];
arrayMaximo = [ [1,5,21,9], [16] ]

for (var y = 0; y < arrayHay.length; y++) {
     str = arrayMaximo[y].toString();
     str = str.replace(/,/g, "-");
     console.log("Cadena nueva:", str);
     $(".reporteBody").append('<div class="cajaResult"><h3>Caja #' + arrayHay[y] + "</h3><p>" + str + "</p></div>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reporteBody"></div>
```

---

Como otra opción, en lugar de usar `replace` podrías haber hecho `join` y ahorrarte el paso intermedio del reemplazo de caracteres:

```js
arrayHay = [1,5];
arrayMaximo = [ [1,5,21,9], [16] ]

for (var y = 0; y < arrayHay.length; y++) {
     str = arrayMaximo[y].join("-");
     console.log("Cadena nueva:", str);
     $(".reporteBody").append('<div class="cajaResult"><h3>Caja #' + arrayHay[y] + "</h3><p>" + str + "</p></div>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reporteBody"></div>
```

Comment: Me sirvio la del `join`por una razón que desconozco la primera no, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Con la funcion replace:

```
str = arrayHay[y];
str.replace(",", "-", "gi");
```

[Fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace#Ejemplos)

Este ejemplo comprobe que funciona.

```
arrayHay = ["1,5,21,9"];
str = arrayHay[0];
alert(str);
var re = /,/gi;
str2 = str.replace(re, "-");
alert( str2 );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado esta solución? Porque no va a funcionar tal cual está escrita.

Comment: @Alvaro, me guié por el ejemplo del link que agregue. Las prueba que hice especificando como flags no me funcionó. Pero si, el ejemplo con expresiones regulares que ahora agregue.